# AngularJS pass index of repeater to function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dynamic table that creates the amount of rows based on the user selection. Each row in the table then has input boxes for numbers. If I have a table with 7 rows for example, I want to store those 7 different inputs into an array. So far I am trying to pass the input of the textbox to a function which updates declared blank arrays. So something like this

HTML

```
 <td id="{{'redScore'+($index+1)}}">
 <input required="" ng-change="updateRedScore(inputValue)" ng-model="inputValue" type="number" step="1" name="rate" min="1" max="10"> </td>
```

Script

```
$scope.redRoundScore = [];    
$scope.inputValue = null;

$scope.updateRedScore = function(passedscore){
   $scope.redRoundScore[index] = passedscore
 }
```

Is there a way I can pass the index alongside the inputValue to updateRedScore?

Comment: Could you not just pass `$index` as a second parameter on your `updateRedScore()` method? This is all inside an `ng-repeat`, right?

Comment: Yes! Sorry I am brand new to angular / js and was just trying to pass index before instead of $index. I will try that and report back

Comment: @Lex Yes indeed that works, so simple :/ Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of completing this question/answer that may help others in the future, adding `$index` as a parameter to the method should work. Also, the `$scope.inputValue = null;` is not needed since the `inputValue` variable only exists on the scope that is created for the `ng-repeat`.

HTML:

```
<td id="{{'redScore'+($index+1)}}">
    <input required 
           ng-change="updateRedScore(inputValue, $index)" 
           ng-model="inputValue" 
           type="number" 
           step="1" 
           name="rate" 
           min="1" 
           max="10">
</td>
```

JS:

```
$scope.redRoundScore = [];
$scope.updateRedScore = function(passedscore, index) {
    $scope.redRoundScore[index] = passedscore
}
```